# Add lines in a boxplot, how to know position of factors on the x-axis?

Tags: r

I want to add lines in a boxplot, and I want to control the location depending on x,x and y,y. I thought I could use the lines function, maybe I can, but how do I know the x position of A, B, C?

```
id <- rep(1:5, each=3)
trt <- rep(LETTERS[1:3],5)
set.seed(1)
q1 <- runif(15)
set.seed(2)
q2 <- runif(15)
set.seed(3)
q3 <- runif(15)


df <- data.frame(id,trt,q1,q2,q3)

boxplot(q3~trt, data=df)
lines([c(1,2)],c(0.7,0.7)) # im thinking from x 1 to x 2, on y 0.7
```

I want to make it similar to this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When plotting the boxplot, save its return value and use it to determine the locations of the factors in the x axis.

```
bp <- boxplot(q3 ~ trt, data = df)

x <- seq_along(bp$names)
y <- c(0.7, 0.7)

lines(x[seq_along(y)], y, lwd = 2) # optional 'lwd', not in the question
```

[image]